# does Django HttpResponseRedirect suffer from xss attack?

Tags: python, django, security, xss, checkmarx

As title, because of urlpatterns are setting numeral parameter, i tend to think that HttpResponseRedirect won't suffer from xss attack, am i right?

If not, how does HttpResponseRedirect suffer from it?

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from hello import views

app_name = 'hello'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    # ex: /hello/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

*views.py*

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('hello:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is generally *secure by default* framework, that means that it should not be vulnerable to the most common attacks (such as XSS, SQLi etc.).

As long as you didn't use `mark_safe()` method ([reference](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)) or `safe` template tag (`<span id="search-query" >You searched for {{ query | safe }}</span>`) you should be safe from XSS attacks etc., because Django automatically escapes dangerous strings.

In your particullar case, XSS is impossible, as your URL accepts integers only (and as far as I understand, it displays only an ID of the question in the browser).

To sum up, for XSS in Django you have to use `{{ something | safe }}` template tag, and load a string with malicious XSS payload to the HTML template.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Is there any chance suffer from xss, if our URL isn't in integers only situation?

Comment: As I said, if you don't use `mark_safe()` method or `safe` template tag for the user-provided data in Django, your app is generally safe from XSS. Of course, there is never a 100% of guarantee, but I haven't seen a XSS in Django for a long time. You can introduce additional protection such as Content Security Policy or X-XSS-Protection header. You can also use DOMPurify - with all of these measures, chances for XSS are close to 0. 

If you find my answer helpful, please vote it up :)